# Why does the name of my flash drive change whenever I demount, then remount it?

Tags: usb

I have a LaCie key (iamakey). When I change the drive's name to "LaCie" then dismount and remount it, it's name changes to "LACIE"
I'm trying to figure out why it won't stay named as "LaCie"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It has always been the case that changing the case of a USB volume formatted with FAT required some low-level hacking.

There are instructions to do this in the following link: (a word of warning: I have not tried this and making a mistake with some of these low level commands may wreck your drive, **so be careful**!)

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090506034709445

Also see the thread here for instructions to change the drive icon if you so desire.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=677658

Comment: All that just to change the case of a name? Geez. Hmm, maybe I'll look into it.

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way. If you reformat the drive to a Mac format the lower case in Finder will stick, but then you can't use the drive in any Windows machine.

Comment: Oh I see. I might just do that, I don't know of any reason why I'd use it with Windows.